# Shapely unary_union on 5 or more Polygons results in empty GeometryCollection

Tags: python, shapely

can anyone tell me why `unary_union` on a sequence of 5 or more Polygons returns an empty `GeometryCollection`:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.ops import unary_union
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

x = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=float)
y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=float)
polygons = []
for i in range(5):
    polygons.append(Polygon(list(zip(x, y))))
    x += 1
un = unary_union(polygons)
```

while 4 or less Polygons returns a Polygon as expected?

```
polygons = []
for i in range(4):
    polygons.append(Polygon(list(zip(x, y))))
    x += 1
un2 = unary_union(polygons)
```

Comment: well, seems to work even with `range(5)` - what version are you using?

Comment: I think this may have been an issue with my cartopy install. The Notebook where I was having this problem had cartopy imported (0.14.2 np111py35_1 from conda-forge). In a new session, with just the code above, `unary_union` worked for >50k polygons. Both sessions were using shapley 1.5.16 with geos 3.5.0. When I went to `conda remove shapely`, it also wanted to remove cartopy.

Comment: Removing and then reinstalling both packages with conda didn't reproduce the above problem but produced this error on running the above code (with cartopy imported before numpy) `Invalid argument (must be a Polygon)
Geometry must be a Point or LineString
Assertion failed: (0 != cs), function GEOSCoordSeq_getSize_r, file geos_ts_c.cpp, line 3797.
Abort trap: 6`